# Android Volley - Checking an Array inside a JSON for a value

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a JSON Object that contains a String array (List of voters).

Here is the JSON Array

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.saveme.ie/api/savings/

My logic goes like

Get the Array into a JSONObject.

Assign the Array in the JSON to a List and check the list for the value.

```
String singleSaving = "";
ArrayList upVoters = new ArrayList();

// Loop through all and get single ID
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        _id2 = obj.getString("_id");

        if (_id2.equals(_id)) {
            singleSaving = _id2;

            // Id like to assign the upVoters array to                           
            // the upVoters ArrayList here

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? and what challenge are you facing with what you tried

Comment: There seems to be no direct way off assigning the Array in the JSON to a local array that i can figure out. I can assign a single string easily using getString but not sure of how to get an array to use the contains()

Comment: have you tried using jackson 2 to directly assign json response to convert object to/from JSON?

Comment: Considering the structure of your json, you can use jackson, gson, okttp or retrofit to deserialize your response from the api, there are online converters you can use to get your POJO like http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com

Comment: @ChrisM have you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate over `upVoters` `JSONArray` and fill the `ArrayList`:

```
String singleSaving = "";
ArrayList upVoters = new ArrayList();

// Loop through all and get single ID
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
        _id2 = obj.getString("_id");

        if (_id2.equals(_id)) {
            singleSaving = _id2;

            // Get upVoters list as JSONArray 
            JSONArray upVotersJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("upVoters");
            for(int j=0; j<upVotersJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                // Fill ArrayList with data from JSON
                upVoters.add(upVotersJsonArray.getString(j));
            }     
        }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```